# How to make an applet connect with an MS Access database?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, applet

> Write an applet which displays the
>   interface for the program described
>   below. When the applet is executed it
>   will display the screen in the
>   appropriate layout, and responds to
>   the user's actions.
>
> The program simulates a student
>   management system having the following
>   characteristics:
>
> The interface is attractive, very user
>   friendly, intuitive (i.e. acts as
>   someone would expect it to act), and
>   reasonably realistic. It must accept
>   the student id,name,age,address,date
>   of birth,gender,blood group etc from
>   the user and save it in MS Access
>   database. + email Id,phone no.,level.
>
> The interface uses command buttons to
>   (i) add,edit,delete,update and cancel
>   the records, (ii) to navigate the
>   records forward or backward (iii) to
>   move directly to first record or last
>   record.    The number of records
>   entered should be displayed using a
>   report when the user presses a
>   "report" button.
>
> Initially make all fields not visible
>   or gray it out.
>
> In the interface appropriately use at
>   least one set of "radio buttons" and
>   at least one "drop-down list". Make
>   appropriate use of the Layout
>   managers.

Comment: OK, at which step exactly are you stucking? That's the question of interest.

Comment: Post what you have done already.

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the MS-Access database by adding it to your ODBC sources.

> To open Data Sources (ODBC), click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Performance and Maintenance. Click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Data Sources (ODBC).

Here is some example code that you can familiarize yourself with. Take a look at the [java.sql.*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) related classes and methods -- you'll find almost all of your answers in there for interacting with the database. Yes, there is some hideous coupling with visual swing classes going on here (you should throw an error instead of just displaying one and forcing a system exit). Also, I think the use of the JdbcOdbcDriver is deprecated as well.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SalesDB
{
    private static Connection connect;

    /**
     * Connects to the database. This method must be run before any of the other methods since
     * this method enables the connection to the database.
     */
    public static void connect()
    {

                //The 'a5q3db' is the name of the ODBC source that you added.
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:a5q3db";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to load JDBC/ODBC driver. Program will now terminate.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to connect to the database. Program will now terminate.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }

    /**
     * close the database connection before the program terminates.
     */
    public static void close()
    {
        try
        {
            connect.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {


        }

    }

    /**
     * Runs the supplied string as a query to the database and returns the result set.
     * @param query The query with which to execute to the database.
     * @return The generated resultset from java.sql.Statement#executeQuery(String).
     */
    public static ResultSet runQuery (String query)
    {
        ResultSet result;

        try
        {

            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeQuery(query);

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }

}//End SalesDB class.
```